# How to find specific JSON value in complex JSON object with Python

Tags: python, json

Hello I have a complex JSON object

```
[
    {
      "InvoiceNumberPrefix": "xx-",
      "InvoiceNumber": 33333,
      "OrderID": 905339301,
      "CustomerID": 44334555,
      "OrderDate": "2020-07-17T12:58:43",
      "OrderStatusID": 1,
      "LastUpdate": "2020-07-17T13:02:12",
      "UserID": "none",
      "SalesPerson": "none",
      "AlternateOrderID": "",
      "OrderType": "Repeat",
      "PaymentTokenID": 0,
      "BillingFirstName": "John",
      "BillingLastName": "Doe",
      "BillingCompany": "3dcart",
      "BillingAddress": "1234 Test St.",
      "BillingAddress2": "",
      "BillingCity": "Tamarac",
      "BillingState": "FL",
      "BillingZipCode": "33321",
      "BillingCountry": "US",
      "BillingPhoneNumber": "33444444",
      "BillingOnLinePayment": false,
      "BillingPaymentMethodID": "177"}
]
```

And I am trying to find specific values in the object. Originally I was able to just specify the location of the key, but the problem is the object can be complex with different key locations. Is there a way to find a specific value? For example if I am trying to see if the JSON object has "33333" in it, what would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: In Python, JSON is just a string of characters unless you convert it into a Python data type. The typical way to do this is with a method from the json library, json.reads(). In your case, have you converted your object into a Python list or is it just a JSON string? (from the way you present it, it looks like the object would convert to a list of dictionaries).

Comment: Sorry there, I meant json.loads(), not json.reads() in the above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to check if a variable is in the values of the converted json dict, then you could do something like this:

```
import json

raw_json = """[{ "InvoiceNumberPrefix": "xx-", 
"InvoiceNumber": 33333, "OrderID": 905339301, 
"CustomerID": 44334555, "OrderDate": "2020-07- 
17T12:58:43", "OrderStatusID": 1, "LastUpdate": "2020-07- 
17T13:02:12", "UserID": "none", "SalesPerson": "none", 
"AlternateOrderID": "", "OrderType": "Repeat", 
"PaymentTokenID": 0, "BillingFirstName": "John", 
"BillingLastName": "Doe", "BillingCompany": "3dcart", 
"BillingAddress": "1234 Test St.", "BillingAddress2": "", 
"BillingCity": "Tamarac", "BillingState": "FL", 
"BillingZipCode": "33321", "BillingCountry": "US", 
"BillingPhoneNumber": "33444444", 
"BillingOnLinePayment": false, "BillingPaymentMethodID": 
"177"} ]"""

myjson = json.loads(raw_json)

def check4value(json_dict, value):
    if value in json_dict.values():
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(check4value(myjson[0], 33333))
#True
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've parsed the JSON into the variable `data` (a list of dictionaries) in Python, you could do:

```
target = '33333'
for i, d in enumerate(data, 1):
    for k, v in d.values():
        if v == target:
            print(f'found target {target} associated with key {k} on dictionary no {i}.'
```